# How to create a file without duplicates (not sorted) with Linux commands?

Tags: linux, command

(I know there's a similar post about this, but the solution given is not working for me as it only works for that case in particular.)

I have something like this (File1.txt):

```
digraph G {
1 [shape="oval" label= "Open"] 
... 
8->9 [style="dashed" label= "true"]
...
2 [shape="oval" label= "Close"] 
8->9 [style="dashed" label= "true"]
...
}
```

And I want a new file that looks like this (File.txt):

```
digraph G {
...
1 [shape="oval" label= "Open"]  
8->9 [style="dashed" label= "true"]
...
}
```

I tried using `sort -u File1.txt >> File.txt` but I don't want it sorted, I need it in the original order.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't want it sorted, shuffle it.

Comment: @n.m. I think he wants the original order (cause that's the only thing that makes any sense)

Comment: That's it. I need it in the original order after removing the duplicates.

Comment: And how do you want 1 and 2 matched, just on `shape="oval"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without sorting with AWK:

```
awk '!x[$0]++' file > newfile
```